# Is there a way to create an animation trail within blender without post-video editing?

Tags: animation, npr

Im a begginer and I am looking to achieve this trail effect ( [Example](https://twitter.com/dimegir/status/1424703587473494016) ) without doing post-video editing, is it possible to achieve within blender itself? Thank you.

Comment: Is this in 3D or 2D, so you have much experience with animation?

Comment: If you're working 3D then I think you're going to be working with smears and duplicated limbs, with the duplicates having a flat shade-less shader. Check out this link for a decent explanationhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNiUO6BwtTc&ab_channel=SirWadeNeistadt In the end animation just takes practice and perseverence

Comment: @James apologies I forgot to specify, I'm working with 3D models, similar to the example, no grease pencil animation nor planes with 2D animation on them, I will be checking the video you linked.